# Is $\lim_{ x \to \infty } f(x) = L \iff \lim_{ x \to - \infty } f(-x) = L$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am currently learning about the limits of real functions - more specifically limits at infinity. And I am wondering, if I have some real function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and some $L \in \mathbb{R}$, is the statement $$\lim_{ x \to \infty } f(x) = L \iff \lim_{ x \to - \infty } f(-x) = L$$true?

Intuitively I want to say yes, because $f(-x)$ is just the reflection in the $y$-axis; so if you flip the function but also reverse directions, then they would cancel each other out. So for example I know that $\lim_{ x \to \infty } e^{-x} = 0$, and reflecting $e^{-x}$ in the $y$-axis gives $e^x$, and I also know that $\lim_{ x \to -\infty } e^x = 0$.

I tried writing a proof for it, so I found these definitions for limits at infinity on Wikipedia:

- Positive infinity: $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists c >0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \ \ x>c \implies \lvert f(x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$
- Negative infinity: $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists c >0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \ \ x<-c \implies \lvert f(x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$

Forward step $\implies$:

Assume $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists c >0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \ \ x>c \implies \lvert f(x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. For some arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, we have $\exists c >0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \ \ x>c \implies \lvert f(x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. Let $c>0$ be the particular number for which that holds. Therefore we have $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \ \ x>c \implies \lvert f(x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be any arbitrary number. Define some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $y = -x$. Therefore, we have $y>c \implies \lvert f(y) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. Assume that $x<-c$, and we know that $x<-c \iff -x > c \iff y > c$. By implication, we have $\lvert f(y) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$; substituting $-x$, we get $\lvert f(-x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. Hence, we have the implication $x<-c \implies \lvert f(-x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. $x$ is an arbitrary number, $c$ is a particular number, and $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrary number, so we have $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists c >0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \ \ x<-c \implies \lvert f(-x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. Therefore, we have the implication $$\lim_{ x \to \infty } f(x) = L \implies \lim_{ x \to - \infty } f(-x) = L$$
Backward step $\impliedby$:

Assume $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists c >0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \ \ x<-c \implies \lvert f(-x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. For some arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, we have $\exists c >0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \ \ x<-c \implies \lvert f(-x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. Let $c>0$ be the particular number for which that holds. Therefore we have $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \ \ x<-c \implies \lvert f(-x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be any arbitrary number. Define some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $y = -x$. Therefore, we have $y<-c \implies \lvert f(-y) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. Assume that $x>c$, and we know that $x>c \iff -x < -c \iff y < -c$. By implication, we have $\lvert f(-y) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. Since, $-y=x$, we get $\lvert f(x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$ by substitution. Hence, we have the implication $x>c \implies \lvert f(x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. $x$ is an arbitrary number, $c$ is a particular number, and $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrary number, so we have $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists c >0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \ \ x>c \implies \lvert f(x) - L \rvert <\varepsilon$. Therefore, we have the implication $$\lim_{ x \to -\infty } f(-x) = L \implies \lim_{ x \to \infty } f(x) = L$$
To me that seems like a valid argument, but I'm not sure; did I make any mistakes? If it is correct, the follow-up question would be: does this mean I can define the limit at negative infinity in terms of the limit at positive infinity? So:
$$
\lim_{ x \to -\infty } f(x) \ := \ \lim_{ x \to \infty } f(-x)
$$

What would be the advantages of defining them explicitly - separately? Is it helpful for generalisations?

Comment: I, personally, find it convincing by substitution.  If we simply replace $y = -x; x=-y$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{-y\to \infty} f(-y)=\lim_{y\to -\infty}f(-y)$ and then as variables are just place holders replace $y$ with the label $x$.

Comment: Glancing at your proof it looks good to me but I didn't comb the details.  But you definitely have the right idea.

Comment: Yes, (long but) correct. However, Wikipedia is not the best reference: you can drop everywhere the positivity of $c$. Note also that @fleablood's substitution amounts to a composition of limits: $$\lim_{+\infty}f=L\implies\lim_{-\infty}f\circ h=L$$ for $h(x):=-x$, because $\lim_{-\infty}h=+\infty.$ Similarly, $$\lim_{+\infty}f=L\impliedby\lim_{-\infty}f\circ h=L$$  because $f=(f\circ h)\circ h$ and $\lim_{+\infty}h=-\infty.$

Comment: I was going to comment before the power went out for eight hours, that in my comment the key item that needs proving is that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = \lim_{-x\to-\infty}g(x)$.  But it's pretty straightforward.   As @AnneBauval points out it's a direct result of composition.  ... or directly $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)= M$ means: For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $R\in \mathbb R$ so that $k > R\implies |g(x)-M| < \epsilon$.  But $x > R \iff -x < -R$ so for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $R'$ (namely $-R$) so that $-x < R'\implies |g(x)-M|< \epsilon$ so $\lim_{-x\to-\infty} g(x) = M$.